# How to get overall JaCoCo coverage locally?

Tags: gradle, jacoco, gradle-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have an android project which has several modules. And the main module is app module.

Here is what I do and could get the separate report. no app/build report.

```
zgong$ ./gradlew jacocoTestReport
zgong$ ls -la */build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
account/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
bootstrap/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
cards/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
common/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
explore/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
launcher/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
payment/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
runtime/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
settings/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
transactions/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
uibase/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
widget/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
```

Could I get a visual report like what I see in the Jenkins report?

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge all reports into a single one.

There are many suggestions here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/merge-jacoco-coverage-reports-for-multiproject-setups/12100/9